# On/Off query in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I use an update query in mysql to change the published row in my db to 1 or 0. Is there a way to do this automatically in one query, ie, if the database had a 1 in published it would set it to 0 and if it had a 0 it would set it to 1... just like a switch?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE tbl SET published = !published WHERE ...
```

Comment: Thanks — please upvote if/when you can.  (I'm glad I went with `!!published` rather than `ABS(SIGN(published - 1))`) :)

Answer (score 8):

Assuming the field's a boolean/bit field, then

```
UPDATE table SET bitfield = ~bitfield
```

where `~` is mysql's bit-wise `NOT` operator.

Answer (score 3):

If the field is `INT`, then:

```
UPDATE table 
SET field = 1 - field
WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a conditional query. Something like this for example

```
UPDATE table SET published = IF(published = 1, 0, 1)
```